# How do I compare a string with a list of strings (without quotes)

Tags: common-lisp

So I recieve a string and I want to compare it with the first element of my list but it wont work because it will compare "asd" with asd if the string is asd.

```
(defun test (thistring list) 
 (cond 
  ((null list) nil) 
  ((equal thistring (car(car list))
     (print "ok")))))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CL-USER 42 > (find "foo" '(bar foo baz) :key #'string-downcase :test #'equal)
```

FOO

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply compare the input string ('thisstring') with the first element of the input list ('list'), then something along these lines would be more suitable:

```
(defun test (thistring list) 
  (cond 
    ((null list)
        nil) 
    ((equal thistring (car list))
        (print "ok"))
  )
)
```